# Eliminar dato desde una tabla vue quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Hola recientemente estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con vue js en quasar y estoy intentando eliminar un registro desde una tabla tan solo presionando el botón con el ícono de la basura y quisiera saber como poder hacerlo, este el código que estaba realizando:

js:

```
 eliminarGuardarEstacion() {     
            let object = {
            idDispositivo: this.proptabla_detalle.cabecera.id_dispositivo,
            idEstacion: this.props.estacion,
            idLinea: this.props.modulo,
            idModulo: this.props.linea                  
            }
            console.log("objeto", object)
            this.$q.loading.show()
            this.$store.dispatch('Dispositivos/ELIMINARESTACION_ACTION', {obj: object}).then(res => {
                if (this.exceptionControl(res)) {
                    this.proptabla_detalle.selected = []
                    this.cargarTabla()
                    this.$q.notify({
                        message: 'Se ha eliminado el registro exitosamente', 
                        timeout: 3000,
                        color: 'positive',
                        position: 'bottom-left'
                    })
                }
                this.$q.loading.hide()
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error('ERROR: ', err)
            })
               
    },
```

y este sería el código para mostrar los datos desde una tabla llamada tabla_detalle en mi vue js:

```
  <template v-slot:body="props">
                                <q-tr :props="props">
                                    <q-td key="estacion" :props="props">
                                        {{ props.row.estacion }}
                                    </q-td>
                                    <q-td key="modulo" :props="props">
                                        {{ props.row.modulo}}
                                    </q-td>
                                    <q-td key="linea" :props="props">
                                        {{ props.row.linea }} Kg
                                    </q-td> 

                                    <q-td>
                                        <q-icon
                                            name="fas fa-trash"
                                            @click.native="eliminarGuardarEstacion(props.row.id_dispositivo)"
                                            size="sm"
                                            class="cursor-pointer"
                                            v-if="props.row.id_dispositivo" 
                                        >
                                            <q-tooltip>
                                                Eliminar
                                            </q-tooltip>
                                        </q-icon>
                                    </q-td>     
                                </q-tr>
                            </template>
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema de este codigo?

Comment: ¿en el boton eliminar estas pasando un objeto al metodo: eliminarGuardarEstacion(props.row.id_dispositivo)? Si es asi en tu funcion (metodo) en ningun momento estas recibiendo el id en tus metodo  debes de poner de la siguiente manera **eliminarGuardarEstacion(id) **

Comment: que no lee los datos para eliminar, creo que estoy llamando de manera erronea los datos que estan en la fila de la tabla hacia mi js, la idea es poder presionar un botón desde una fila q-table y que reconozca los datos de la fila que estoy presionando para eliminar